# android 4.4 print word document in reduced scale

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, android-print-framework

My android app (android 4.4) needs to print out some word document (.doc). The documents are in A4-size but my client's receipt is in A5-size format. I have checked the developer documentation (link in below) but it only talks about pdf.

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

Is there any print example related to .doc?